# how can i send image object from php to Java webservice

Tags: java, web-services

I need a suggestion. Iam developing the face recognistion webservice (SOAP) in java, but front end is php application. User will send the image either by capturing using webcam or uploading the image. But i want this image and its detials as File Object in xml instead path from the server or database. Please suggest me how can i handle this or any other approaches.

Comment: Take a look at MTOM, which is preferred over using base64 inline. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1916377/building-large-mtom-xop-messages-with-jax-ws

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at one of these:

```
$requestImageXML = '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode(readfile($filePath)) . '"/>';
$requestImageString = base64_encode(readfile($filePath));
```

and use the string in a relevant way.